# Open local HTML file in Iframe from AppFolder in WinJS

Tags: javascript, iframe, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am writing Windows store app using WinJS Library. I am using IFrame to load Local HTML files.

```
<iframe id="iframe_Id" onload="Load();" src="/html/OPS/chapter_001.xhtml"></iframe>
```

Here the file contains in my Solution Explorer.

But I want to open from my app folder which is path :

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\c1c70291-897c-4c49-9efc-e2bfe03de92f_vkg0nyxnnp64t\LocalState\Cinderella_Or_The_Little_Glass_Slipper\OPS\000Title.html
```

So opening appfolder I am doing like this

```
<iframe id="iframe_Id" onload="Load();" src="ms-appdata:///Cinderella_Or_The_Little_Glass_Slipper/OPS/000Title.html"></iframe>
```

But it is not working at all. I know I can load Local HTML files suggested from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9f5b56bd-8440-4e7b-a5ef-9916059928e7/control-to-load-html-content-in-javascript-store-apps?forum=winappswithhtml5)

Please suggest me. I got struck here.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the `WebView`? (It's far more capable of a web host).

Comment: I can't restrict Zoom in WebView;I don't have webhost content & I have only Local HTML Content in my AppFolder. FYI I tried webview in Windows 8 XAML & after I realized to develop in HTML/WinJS.
If u know any info about my post Plz help me.
Thanks.

Comment: The WebView exists in Win 8.1 SDK for WinJS.

Comment: Yes. I tried it. I guess still we can't disable zoom of webview. Because I didn't see any property to disable zoom on webview. I tried it today in WinJS; Why bcz my app is Reader for Epub.Zooming is not relevant for reader...

Comment: How can you disable it on an iFrame but not a WebView (which is more capable)?

Comment: By default the content in iFrame can't zoom & I am not sure about webview; 
AFAIK When you use webview you can't load Images in webview from Local which contians in HTML page.. So You ahve to convert into base64; etc...

Comment: @WiredPrairie Look at this.. the MSFT people are telling it is possible.. But we have add Script to content..
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/ed22c6a1-cfb6-45a0-b3b3-cf46d6d2b2c2/open-local-html-file-in-iframe-from-appfolder-in-winjs?forum=winappswithhtml5#817b898f-d2ba-4de8-a201-a81e84f82a36

Answer (score -1):

try with changing `src` link.

`src="ms-appdata:///local/Cinderella_Or_The_Little_Glass_Slipper/OPS/000Title.html"`

eye on first local!